# how to use angular $animate with a dynamic computed changing css style

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I am trying to create a directive that will animate the height of the element.
The problem is that i am calculating the height of the element based on the data, so i can't create in advance a class that i will add with animate.

I need to add the height property with a different value each time

this is my current directive:

```
.directive('graph', ['$document', '$animate', function ($document, $animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

            var newClass = {height: attributes['height']}

            $animate.addClass(element, newClass);

        }
    };
}]);
```

but this won't work. what should be the solution?

what if i will use instead:

```
element.css({height: newClass});
```

this will work but then why do i have the $animate service if i can do it as simple as this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(element).animate({height: "-=" + value + "px"}, function() {...});
```